# Find cosine of the angles whose vertices are given points

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I'm studying for an upcoming test and found the following problem.

> Find cosine of the inner angles of the triangle whose vertices are: $(3, 1, 1)$,
> $(−1, 2, 1)$, $(2, −2, 5)$.

I was wondering if my solution is correct. Here's what I did.

---

> Note: [a, b, ...] denotes a vector with componentes $a$, $b$, etc.

Let $\vec{A}, \vec{B}, \vec{C}$ be the vectors pointing at each of the given points, respectively. The vectors that appropriately represent the sides of the triangle formed by these three points are

- $\vec{A}-\vec{B}= [4,  -1, 0]$
- $\vec{A}-\vec{C}= [1, 3,  -4]$
- $\vec{B}-\vec{C}=[-3, 4, -4]$

We shall use the fact that $\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}}{|\vec{v}||\vec{w}|}$ for the angle $\theta$ formed by the vectors $\vec{w}, \vec{w}$. Let $\vec{v}, \vec{w}, \vec{u}$ be each of the vectors computed above, respectively. Notice that $|\vec{v}|=\sqrt{17}, |\vec{w}|=\sqrt{26}, |\vec{u}|=\sqrt{41}$. Then

$i.$ $\cos \theta =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}\sqrt{2
6}}$ is the cosine of the inner angle formed by $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$

$ii.$ $\cos \beta =  -\frac{26}{\sqrt{17}\sqrt{41}}$ is the cosine of the inner angle formed by $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$.

$iii.$ $\cos \lambda =  -\frac{25}{\sqrt{41}\sqrt{26}}$ is the cosine of the inner angle formed by $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$.

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that two of the angles you have computed are obtuse since the cosine values are negative, so your solution cannot be correct.

The error has occurred in calculating angle $\beta$. The internal angle at $B$ is found by calculating the dot ptoduct of $\overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$, whereas you have found the exterior angle there by using $\overrightarrow{AB}$ instead.

Comment: I see. I computed it all again "the right way" and it turns the correct angle at each case was the absolute value of my wrong angles. I take it this follows from the fact that $\vec{QP}=(-1)\vec{PQ}$. So the correct answers were $\frac{1}{\sqrt{26}\sqrt{17}}, \frac{16}{\sqrt{17}\sqrt{41}}, \frac{25}{\sqrt{26}\sqrt{41}}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use the cosine formula. First chose the largest side, say it is BC=a. Then the largest angle  $$\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=\frac{26+17-41}{2\sqrt{26.17}}>0$$
A  is acute. Similarly find B and C.